# Which proposition relates me to a codebase I am working on?

Tags: translation

Applying as a programmer in a German company, I would like to translate the sentence “I made my first steps in language X working on a 20 year old industrial codebase.“ I came up with “Ich habe meine ersten Schritte mit der Sprache X an einer 20 Jahre alte industrielle Codebase gemacht.”  I picked the proposition “an“ because “man arbeitet an etwas” but I am not sure if this is actually appropriate.

Comment: Could you rephrase/paraphrase what "working on an old code base" means precisely?

Comment: @Emanuel codebase is a technical term used in IT (see Wikipedia), apart from this, I am not sure about what could need to be clarified. Could you clarify your clarification request? :)

Comment: I'm not looking for something in particular that would need clarification. I'd just like a paraphrase because I am not sure about the thing as a whole. I sort of get it but in order to really give you a translation that is spot on, the thing to be expressed has to be crystal clear. For instance... is it an old code base of yours in a different language or is it an old code base of someone else in the target language. The sentence as it stands allows for both readings. Also how important is "old"? Would "pre-existing code" change the meaning?

Comment: @Emanuel, I see. This is a 20 years old industrial codebase (mostly) written in the same language X.  It is old as in the text “big ball of mud“.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich kenne keine Entsprechung für "codebase", man muss es wohl durch ein anderes in den Kontext passendes Substantiv ersetzen.

> Ich habe meine ersten Schritte in der Programmiersprache X beim Arbeiten am Quellcode einer 20 Jahre alten Industriesoftware gemacht.

Man sollte vielleicht dazusagen, ob die 20 Jahre vom damaligen Zeitpunkt oder von heute aus gesehen sind.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde Codebase nicht unbedingt verwenden (Anglizismus) und erst recht nicht eindeutschen (Kodebasis? brrr...)

Statt dessen würde ich sagen "Ich habe meine ersten Schritte in C++ im alten Foobar-Projekt gemacht."

Comment: It is definitely a valuable advice!

Comment: I don't know why, but your suggestion doesn't sound very natural to me.

Comment: Why not use "Codebasis"?

Comment: @TheBlastOne Weil base x Bedeutungen hat, und nur eine davon Basis ist, und das ist noch nicht mal die wichtigste Bedeutung. Wenn man von der deutschen Bedeutung des Wortes Basis ausgeht, passt es noch weniger: Basis als Hauptquartier, Grundlage oder Fußgestell --- das passt nach meinem Sprachgefühl nicht zu Code. Klingt eher wie ein lieblos aus dem Englischen übernommener Begriff.

Comment: Also ich als Entwickler fänd's passend, wenn auch nur gefühlt.

Comment: Hat es im Deutschen nicht ebensoviele Bedeutungen?